# Including JPGRAPH library into a Zend framework project

Tags: zend-framework, jpgraph

When trying to include the JPGRAPH library in a Zend Studio project, I got the error

> Fatal error: Class 'Graph' not found in C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\NewStokV4\application\controllers\StatsController.php on line 49

when executing my code.

I tried to follow, unsuccessfully, some tutorials on the net, but none were complete nor clear to me. (I'm new in Zend framework development.)

this is what i get when trying include... or require...

> Warning: require_once(vendors/jpgraph-3.5.0b1/src/jpgraph.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\NewStokV4\application\controllers\StatsController.php on line 15
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required  'vendors/jpgraph-3.5.0b1/src/jpgraph.php' (include_path='C:\Program Files\Zend \Apache2\htdocs\NewStokV4\vendors\Oft_Framework-G1R1C0/vendors/minify-2.1.5/min/lib;C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\NewStokV4\vendors\Oft_Framework-G1R1C0/vendors/htmlpurifier-4.4.0/library;C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\NewStokV4\vendors\ZendFramework-1.10.7\library;C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\NewStokV4\vendors\Oft_Framework-G1R1C0\library;C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\NewStokV4/library;C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\NewStokV4\vendors\ZendFramework-1.10.7\extras\library') in C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\NewStokV4\application\controllers\StatsController.php on line 15

Comment: Where is the `JPGRAPH` libary located and how do you include it?

Comment: well i have the folder containing jpgraph classes and stuff, & the inclusion is what s causing me the problème, i tried including it in PHP include path, by specifying the jpgraph folder path, but it didn t work!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your comment:

**Solution A (a bit dirty)**

Put the whole `JPGRAPH` library inside `\library\jpgraph` folder an include it inside your controller via:

```
require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/jpgraph/jpgraph.php');
```

**Solution B (better)**

Check if jpgrah uses namespaces. if yes you might want try to load it with the build in autoloader function of zend.  Put the whole `JPGRAPH` library inside `\library\JPGraph` folder.

Usage: just add `autoloaderNamespaces[] = "<jpgraph_namespace>"` to your `application.ini` where `<jpgraph_namespace>` is the namespace of jpgraph.

*So assuming the namespace is `JPGraph`:*

application.ini:

```
[...]

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

[...]

autoloaderNamespaces[] = "JPGraph"
```

in your controller:

```
[...]

$JPGraph = new JPGraph();

[...]
```

Comment: by a quick look on the net, it seems that jpgraph doesn t have a namespace, & when trying solution A, here is the error: Warning: require_once(vendors/jpgraph-3.5.0b1/src/jpgraph.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\NewStokV4\application\controllers\StatsController.php on line 15